# Comparing Textbox values in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Am comparing 2 values in text box

say `$('#Low'.val()) > $('#High'.val())  //Where low and high are textbox id`

But it is fails in few scenarios as it is comparing string.

i have 2 questions here

1.how to convert to integer or float and check it in correct way

2.When i compare the string as per my above code "99"  > "1000" is returning true. Why it succeeds ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
parseInt($('#Low'.val(),10)) > parseInt($('#High'.val(),10))
```

or

```
 parseFloat($('#Low'.val())) > parseFloat($('#High'.val())
```

Comment: And "parseFloat" similarly

Answer (score 1):

Even better is to use parseFloat.

```
parseFloat($('#Low').val())) > parseFloat($('#High').val())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used function as `$('#Low'.val())` which is wrong. It should be `$('#Low').val()`

Do this way:-

```
parseInt($('#Low').val(), 10) > parseInt($('#High').val(), 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
(parseInt($("#Low").val()) > parseInt($('#High').val()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alphabetically 9 comes after 1. So "99" > "1000" may return true.

```
if(parseInt($('#Low'.val())) > parseInt($('#High'.val()))
{
    //Yes, #Low is bigger than #High
}
else
{
    //No, #Low is not bigger than #High yet.
}
```

must work.